# Laravel UTF-8 To Database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent to save() a new person into my database. The persons name contains a special character **é** and it's not submitting. Here are my steps and the results.

```
echo Input::get('firstname'); // Miguél
```

Which gives me this

### Miguél

When i start using eloquent the following happens.

```
$person = new Person();
echo $person->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
```

This produces the following result

### migu��l

Any idea what might be going wrong?
These are my config settings in laravel

[image]

And this is my database in phpmyadmin

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What type of DB are you using ? What is its encoding ?

Comment: I'm using MySql, Charset is set to utf8 and collation is utf8_general_ci. i'll add my settings to the question

Comment: It your database itself also set as utf8 ?

Comment: What @YellowBird said. Check if the actual database in MySQL was created with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my phpmyadmin where you can see the database settings. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think it has anything common with database.

When you use:

```
$person = new Person();
echo $person->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
```

you don't use database in here. You just assign properties to Person class (that probably uses Eloquent) but you don't put anything into database and get anything from database so it's not possible that the encoding problem has anything in common with database itself

Potential problem in my opinion - you have defined mutator in `Person` class for `firstname` attribute because you have it in lowercase (when you get it from Input it's with capital letter) so you probably use some function like `strtolower` and you should use `mb_strtolower` to convert UTF-8 strings without a problem.

Comment: That's it! How clever of you. I didn't even post the strtolower() code. is mb_strtolower() good practice? or is there another way i should do this!

Comment: @MiguelStevens For any operations on UTF-8 strings you should use `mb_` functions to handle national characters without a problem - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php