# MySQL won't store "€"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, special-characters

I am working on a application where I need to store/show data containing many special characters. I have set database collation `utf8`. I have set collation of table `utf8` and character set as `utf8_unicode_ci`. It is storing all special characters like `Ã©`, `â`. But whenever a character ,`€` comes it isn't stored as it is. Like whenever there is a word `â€œattributedâ€` it becomes `âattributedâ`. I am currently using Laravel 5.2 (PHP) .

**What I have tried so far**
I have set following in my code

```
  iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

I have also tried

```
$value = array_map("utf8_encode", $array);
```

But this special character isn't getting stored as it is. Will any one let me know what should I do to get this special character saved as it is.

Comment: have you tried using `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37724) post? It advices to change the encoding type

Comment: Is your data going through a URL? How is this data obtained? Have you tried outputting it on screen?

Comment: @itsols I am getting data from a csv. before sending in database, I have outputed the data in browser and it goes well but not stored as it is in databaase

Comment: Does it also not work if you insert it via the MySQL command line?

Comment: MySQL collation `utf8_uni_code` does not exist. You can get a list of available values with `SHOW COLLATION`. I'm pretty sure Laravel defaults to UTF-8 so everything you try in your code will just corrupt data.

Comment: [UTF-8 All the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Sorry that was written mistakenly. It is actually `utf8_unicode_ci`. I have updated my question as well

Comment: BTW, `Ã©` and `â€œ` are **not** correct. That's what you get if you properly store `é` and `“` as UTF-8 and then misprint them as e.g. Windows-1252. What's your Laravel database configuration? You are using a framework, you should be trying to address this at framework level, not patching all around.

Comment: I think I know your issue. Try this. First create a UTF encoded textfile. Then paste your contents in it. Now try using it with MySQL. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your collation to "utf8_general_ci" in your mysql

Comment: have you still got your encoding in your php file in place?

Comment: can you try take it out and insert without the php encoding

Comment: without php encoding it converts this symbol to quotes

Answer (score 0):

Normally its no problem to store the `€` sign to a database field. Check if all your scripts are in a correct coding.

Set your table and all data in that table to `utf8_general_ci` then try to change your php file to UTF-8.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And if you have incorrect data then use.

```
utf8_encode("test");
```

to encode your string to a correct UTF-8 string. If that isn't working i think your data or string your try to convert is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

For being able to use UTF8 characters in your queries you must run a certain query setting this, just like this:

```
$db->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

But I've seen that you said you're using Laravel. I haven't been working on it, but I guess this's automatically set by the `charset` parameter written in config, just like in the screenshot of this question:
[Laravel UTF-8 To Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343876/laravel-utf-8-to-database)